# Is it possible to use nidi.guru Graphviz implementation in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, graphviz

Is it possible to use guru nidi Graphviz implementation in Android Studio. Their implementation is available from maven. I have tried to use it in AndroidStudio, but error I get is:

Program type already present: com.eclipsesource.v8.NodeJS$2

The source code of their implementation is: https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java

My gradle is:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    //preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "rs.etf.igor.algorithmsimulation"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'license/LICENSE.dom-documentation.txt'
        exclude 'license/NOTICE'
        exclude 'license/README.dom.txt'
        exclude 'license/LICENSE.dom-software.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'license/LICENSE'
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8:4.8.0@aar'
implementation 'guru.nidi:graphviz-java:0.2.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
```

}

King Regards,
Igor Vurdelja

Comment: Did you try to remove `com.eclipsesource.j2v8`? And keep graphviz? Also, it's not clear how you're planning on displaying the generated output on Android

Comment: Yes, i have tried to remove it, same error. I want to generate graph as a SVG and to show it in my app.

Comment: Apparently, some classes are already loaded, and i don't know from where they are. Do you know how to exclude this class? For now i have this:                   configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.eclipsesource.v8', module: 'NodeJS$2'
    } , but this isn't right